# Update table according to row number in C# sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I am writing a small program using an SQL database. The table name is `StudentInfo`.
I need to know the SQL code for the following

```
for (n=0; n<nRows; n++) {
  string sql1="update StudentInfo set Position=" + n + " where <this has to be the row number>";
}
```

`nRows` is number of rows.

How can I get the row number for the above code?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You cannot count on the database maintaining the rows order in any consistent manner without some sort of record identifier or key or applying a sort.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is to create a stored procedure in the database and use your code to pass the relevent information to the server

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this task you'll want to create a *Stored Procedure* or build a *Query* that actually accepts parameters.  This will help you pass variables between, your method of *concatenation* will actually cause an error or become susceptible to *SQL Injection attacks*.

*Non Parameter SQL Command:*

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Database Connection String Here"))
{
     string command =
           "UPDATE Production.Product " +
           "SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2 " +
           "WHERE ProductID IN " +
               "(SELECT ProductID  " +
                "FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor" +
                "WHERE BusinessEntityID = 1540);" +

     using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command, sqlConnection))
     {
           int execute = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           if( execute <= 0)
           {
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               return true;
           }
     }
}
```

That method is essentially creation a connection, running our *SQL Command*, then we are using an *integer* to verify that it did indeed run our command successful.  As you can see we simply using *SQL* to run our command.

The other important thing to note, **you can't create a sub-query with an update; you have to create an update then run a select as the sub-query to hone in more specific data across so you can span across tables and so on.**

The other alternative would be to use a parameter based query, where your passing variables between *SQL* and your *Application*.

I won't post code to that, because I believe you wrote the C# loop to demonstrate what you would like *SQL* to do for you. Which is only update particular rows; based on a specific criteria.

If you could post additional information I'd be more then happy to help you.  But I'm just going to post what I believe you are trying to accomplish.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is that what you were attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, and it's successful. Thank you :)